# c# - Post knockout array to an IEnumerable object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, model-binding

I am really noob at this.
I'm using knockout to save data from frontend to backend. What I want to do is save a knockout array to a IEnumerable object in c#

```
public class VDenuncia
{
    public int IdDenuncia { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<VFiles> Files { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see below this is my Model

```
public class VFiles
{
    public int IdFile { get; set; }
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }

}
```

And this is the model for Files.

First I save the files to a DB and return the ID of the insert, i want to save that ID in VDenuncia with knockout but don't know how to develop it.

I'm using ajax for go to JS to C# but when converting observableArray to IEnumerable does not get any object in C#

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Home/Save',
            data: { denuncia: data },
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
```

Save action from HomeController

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Save(VDenuncia denuncia)
    {
        var manager = new DenunciaManager();
        var result = await manager.SaveDenuncia(denuncia);

        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = result.Folio,
            MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```

This is the value of data.

```
var data = {
  Name: self.Name(),
  LastName: self.LastName(),
  FirstName: self.FirstName(),
  Files: ({
      IdFile: self.IdFile(),
      File: self.File(),
      Extension: self.Extension(),
    })
};
```

**SOLUTION:**

The solution that is given works, but I realized that I was working with arrays and I only change on data what is next:

```
Files: [{
  IdFile: self.IdFile(),
  File: self.File(),
  Extension: self.Extension(),
}]
```

Comment: Can you share your "Save" action from the HomeController?

Comment: Sure, I already edit my question

Comment: Post code, not images of it. And what is the value of `data`. If its in the correct format, it will bind fine (but most likely you will need to stringify the data and use `contentType: 'json'`)

Comment: There is the content of data, I guess i'm making everything alright but does not work

Comment: Change `data: { denuncia: data },` to `JSON.stringify({ denuncia: data })` and add `contentType: 'json',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should unwrap the observables in your object and then stringify your javascript object to JSON.

use ko.mapping module to unwrap your javascript object easily like this :

```
var payload = ko.mapping.toJS(data); //unwrap your observables
```

and then set the type as json in your ajax request and convert `payload` to JSON using `JSON.stringify(payload)` as in the following :

```
var ajaxOptions = {
                url: 'Home/Save',
                data: JSON.stringify(payload),
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
            };
```

Comment: This does not work, the problem is in ajax when send data, I receive in mvc wrapped but in object Files it says "null"

Comment: @JonathanAxel change the byte[] type of the property 'File' to 'HttpPostedFileBase' (google that) and then read the stream in that object into bytes. however, if you are looking to upload files through ajax you might want to look into the jquery-blueimp plugin to achieve multiple browser support.